# ModelMapper: How to set a destination property based on whether collection in source has elements

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have an entity to dto conversion that is managed by ModelMapper. My specification has been modified, and now I need to add a boolean property to the DTO determining whether a collection in the entity has elements.

So, if my entity looks something like:

```
public class MyEntity {
  private Integer id;
  private String someField;
  @OneToMany
  private Set<Foo> foos;
  private Date createdDate;
  private Date modifiedDate;
  private Integer version;

  // getters & setters
}
```

and my updated DTO looks something like:

```
public class MyEntityDto {
  private Integer id;
  private String someField;
  private Boolean hasFoos;

  // getters & setters
}
```

I convert from entity to DTO in a stream:

```
public List<MyEntityDto> convert(List<MyEntity) l) {
  return l.stream
    .map(this::toDto)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

To meet the updated specification, I modified the `toDto` method to add the boolean value manually, but I'm not entirely happy with it and would prefer to convert in ModelMapper, if only as an academic exercise.

```
private MyEntityDto toDto(MyEntity e ) {
    MyEntityDto dto =  modelMapper.map(e, MyEntityDto.class);
    dto.setHasFoos(e.foos.size() > 0);
    return dto;
}
```

So, my question is, how can I set the DTO's boolean `hasFoos` property based on whether the Set in the entity has elements using only the ModelMapper API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up [typeMap](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#converters) to convert specific fields of classes with your own converters.

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
Converter<Set, Boolean> SET_TO_BOOLEAN_CONVERTER =
        mappingContext -> !mappingContext.getSource().isEmpty();

modelMapper.createTypeMap(MyEntity.class, MyEntityDto.class)
    .addMappings(mappings -> mappings.using(SET_TO_BOOLEAN_CONVERTER)
                            .map(MyEntity::getFoos, MyEntityDto::setHasFoos));
```

Comment: Can't get this working. My IDE doesn't recognize `using` as a method on the passed lambda argument. Compilation results in two errors `cannot infer type - variable(s) V` for `DestinationSetter` in the `addMappings` arguments. It also throws a non-static method cannot be referenced from static context for the `map` call. Using `modelmapper-spring@2.3.0`.

Comment: Are you sure that you use `addMappings` and not `addMapping`?